# Angular 2 Bind a variable to a header in html

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to bind a variable to a header to show what the current step is (ie, 'You are on step 1 of 10'). I have it working for a textarea and can't figure out why it doesn't work for a header.

```
private mainStepText: String = "Welcome";
<div class="mainWindow">
   <textarea [(ngModel)]="mainStepText"></textarea> 
</div>
```

What I have so far is

```
private testLabel: String = "This is a test label for html";
<div class="test">
  <h3 class="labelName" [(ngModel)]="testLabel"></h3>
</div>
```

Right now it throws an error

"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of ngModel in the tag. Just do:

```
<h3 class="labelName">{{testLabel}}</h3>
```

and set testLabel in your component

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for, worked perfectly.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.